# How to grant permission for a user to all tables and sequences?

Tags: oracle, privileges

How to grant permission for a user to all tables and sequences in Oracle?

Answer (score 0):

**Tables:**

```
BEGIN
   FOR R IN (SELECT owner, table_name FROM all_tables WHERE owner='<<REPLACE_WITH_YOUR_SCHEMA>>') LOOP
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'grant select on '||R.owner||'.'||R.table_name||' to <<REPLACE_WITH_USER>>';
   END LOOP;
END;
```

**Sequences:**

```
BEGIN
   FOR R IN (SELECT sequence_owner, sequence_name FROM all_sequences WHERE sequence_owner='<<REPLACE_WITH_YOUR_SCHEMA>>') LOOP
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'grant select on '||R.sequence_owner||'.'||R.sequence_name||' to <<REPLACE_WITH_USER>>';
   END LOOP;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

This query can be used to set the appropriate system privileges.

```
 GRANT SELECT ANY TABLE TO SOMEUSERNAME;
 GRANT SELECT ANY SEQUENCE TO SOMEUSERNAME;
```

More information can be found here:
https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/GRANT.html#GUID-20B4E2C0-A7F8-4BC8-A5E8-BE61BDC41AC3